# How to filter from two conditions?

Tags: python, django

I have a model for user groups:

```
class ProfileGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(user)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And a model for article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(ProfileGroup)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

The user can edit own articles and articles from groups which is assigned.

How to retrieve all user articles and from his groups? Do I need to use Q? Maybe suffice filter?

```
articles = Article.object.filter(....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a user's articles:

```
Article.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

To get articles that belong to one of the user's groups.

```
Article.objects.filter(group__user=user)
```

You can then get use `Q` to get articles which belong to that user or one of the user's groups.

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(owner=user)|Q(group__user=user))
```